# MySQL: Column automaticly current time of insert

Tags: mysql

I am creating a new table, and I would like each row to have a column that is equal to the time that the row is inserted into the table. Is there a way to do this in the create table statement or do I have to do this in my insert statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  timeStampColumn TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this when creating the table.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  insert_timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The TIMESTAMP data type offers automatic initialization and updating to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp).[MORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

```
TIMESTAMP
```

**sample**

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set default value as NOW like

```
    CREATE TABLE example (
     id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
     data VARCHAR(140),
     created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
     );
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e336/1)

[Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id int,
  update_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```