# Automatically Initialize GETDATE() when inserting into MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

~[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700239/mysql-column-automaticly-current-time-of-insert) ~[w3schools perhaps helpful link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp)

~Problem: I'm inserting rows into a mysql database and I want each row to have a column where the current date(date when row was inserted) is shown.

~Attempted solution:

```
CREATE TABLE $this->DB.$table
              (
              id int,
              Report_Date date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE ON UPDATE CURRENT_DATE)//this fails.
```

Would someone also explain what ON UPDATE means? I'm nervous that when I have multiple days of data it will update all values of Report_Date and mess up my data. The solution lies somewhere in GETDATE, I think. Furthermore I do not want time, only date. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. As documented under [`CREATE TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table.html) (emphasis added):

   > The `DEFAULT` clause specifies a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. **This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) or [`CURRENT_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date).** The exception is that you can specify [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp) as the default for a [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) or (as of MySQL 5.6.5) [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) column. See [Section 11.3.5, “Automatic Initialization and Updating for `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME`”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

   Therefore your options are:

   - use a `TIMESTAMP` column (since MySQL v5.6.5, you can also use a `DATETIME` column) and ignore the time part;
   - explicitly specify the current date in the `INSERT` command:

     ```
     INSERT INTO myTable (id, Report_Date) VALUES (123, CURRENT_DATE)
     ```
   - define a `BEFORE INSERT` [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html):

     ```
     CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON myTable FOR EACH ROW
       SET NEW.Report_Date = IFNULL(NEW.Report_Date, CURRENT_DATE)
     ```
2. > Would someone also explain what ON UPDATE means?

   As documented under [Automatic Initialization and Updating for `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

   > - An auto-initialized column is set to the current timestamp for inserted rows that specify no value for the column.
   > - An auto-updated column is automatically updated to the current timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed from its current value. An auto-updated column remains unchanged if all other columns are set to their current values. To prevent an auto-updated column from updating when other columns change, explicitly set it to its current value. To update an auto-updated column even when other columns do not change, explicitly set it to the value it should have (for example, set it to [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp)).

Comment: So this works perfectly, And it isn't an issue for me to explicitly mention CURRENT_DATE in the insert statement. But it's my understanding that if I create the table correctly, I can simply _not_ specify the CURRENT_DATE and when the row is created it would auto-magically put the current date in there. How would I create the table so that I don't have to mention Report_Date or CURRENT_DATE in my insert? This solution solves my issue entirely, I just want to improve my sql-mojo.

Comment: @J-Dizzle: You can define a trigger to set the column value - see my update, above.

Comment: Sweet, I appreciate the multitude of solutions. I'd +2 the answer if I could! --they say you shouldn't say "thanks" in comments, but how else would people know that I've got the answer I need? Thanks!

Comment: @J-Dizzle: The green tick indicates that, but your comment is very much appreciated.  :)