# How do you update a datetime field in a table every time another field in the same table gets updated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table called YearTable with three columns (Year, Status, and LastUpdatedTime).  Every time someone adds/updates a value into the year or status column LastUpdatedTime needs to be updated.  I wrote a trigger for this, but now every time I try to add a new record I get an error message:

ErrorSource: .NetSqlClient Data Provider.
Error Message: Cannot insert the value NULL into Column 'Year', table 'Budget.YearTable'; column does not allow nulls.  Insert fails.

This is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateTrigger
ON  YearTable
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

insert into tblaudit(LastUpdatedTime)
values(GETDATE())

END
GO
```

Comment: The code didn't copy over correctly:

Comment: ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateTrigger]
   ON  [dbo].[YearTable]
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
 
 insert into YearTable(LastUpdatedTime)
 values(GETDATE())
 

END

Comment: [similar but not dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054028/automatically-initialize-getdate-when-inserting-into-mysql)

Comment: Is your trigger inserting into the `YearTable` or the `tblAudit` table?  You have one listed in the question, and a different one listed in the comment...

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, I fixed it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated:

> I wrote a trigger for this, but now every time I try to add a new record I get an error message:
>
> ErrorSource: .NetSqlClient Data Provider. Error Message: Cannot insert the value NULL into Column 'Year', table 'Budget.YearTable'; column does not allow nulls. Insert fails.

From this, does this mean your `updates` and `deletes` are working?  If that is the case, then it sounds like just like the error message states.  When you're doing an `insert` into the table, you aren't supplying a value for the `year` column on the `YearTable`.

Have you tried disabling the trigger and seeing if the behavior exists when doing the same operations?

After further consideration of your question, I'm now ***assuming*** you're meaning that when a row in `YearTable` is updated, that that same row in `YearTable` has its `LastUpdated` column updated.  Though now I'm not really sure where your `tblAudit` is coming from.  Or why you would have the trigger created for `deletes` when there would be no row to update at that point.

I'm going to assume that your key on the table is `year` - if you don't currently have a key, you probably need one.

To handle the `LastUpdated` for inserts/updates you could use the following in your trigger (assuming year is your key):

```
UPDATE YearTable
SET LastUpdated = GetDate()
FROM inserted
where YearTable.Year = inserted.year
```

Comment: Yeah the tblAudit was a mistake.  I fixed the table name in the comment section.  Thank you for your help.  That fixed my issue.

Comment: no problem, you can edit the question in the future to fix that mistake :)

Comment: Would you know how to update this to add the user name of whoever made the update as well (using windows authentication)?

Comment: How would the trigger get access to such information?  You would need to pass the username in as a part of all updates/inserts in order to record the username, it can't be handled in a trigger as far as i know